# How to Write a Summation of Fives in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, sum

I need to write a program in Java that can take the multiples of five up to a value given by the user, and then add all of the multiples together. I need to write it with a while loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SummationOfFives {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //variables
        double limit;
        int fives = 0;

        //Scanner
        System.out.println("Please input a positive integer as the end value: ");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        limit = input.nextDouble();

        //While Loop
        while ((fives+5)<=limit)
        {
            fives = fives+5;
            System.out.println("The summation is: "+fives);
       }
    }
}
```

When I run this program however, all it gives me is the multiples:

```
Please input a positive integer as the end value: 
11
The summation is: 5
The summation is: 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there! Think about what your output is telling you.  In your `while` loop, `fives` is the next multiple of 5 on each iteration.  You're not adding it to a total variable anywhere.

So - define a total before the loop e.g.

```
int total = 0;
```

keep adding to it in the loop (where your `System.out.println` is now) e.g.

```
total = total + fives;
```

output the total after the loop e.g.

```
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a total variable into your loop that will accumulate the value of all of the summations.

```
    int counter =1;
    int total = 0;
    //While Loop
    while ((fives+5)<=limit)
    {
        total = counter*5;
        counter++;
        fives = fives+5;
        System.out.println("The summation is: "+fives);
        System.out.println("The total is: "+total);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The summation you do in `fives` is wrong. You need another variable `multiple` initialised to `0` that you will increment by 5 at each step of the loop. The stop condition in the `while` is `(multiple < limit)`. Then `fives` are the sum of the `multiple`s.

```
    double limit;
    int fives = 0;
    int multiple = 0

    //While Loop
    while (multiple<=limit)
    {
        multiple += 5;
        fives = fives + multiple;
        System.out.println("So far, the summation is: "+fives);
   }
```